# Nginx container doesn't use nginx.conf unless I restart the container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

As the title says, my nginx container is not working as expected unless I restart it. I have several services defined in a `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like this: `reverseproxy` is my nginx container, and `service-a` and `service-b` are Node.js servers.

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  reverseproxy:
    container_name: reverseproxy
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  service-a:
    container_name: service-a
    build:
      context: ./service-a
    ports:
      - "3500:3500"
    command: ["yarn", "run", "watch-debug"]
  service-b:
    container_name: service-b
    build:
      context: ./service-b
    ports:
      - "3501:3501"
    command: ["yarn", "run", "watch-debug"]
```

The `Dockerfile` used to build my `reverseproxy` service simply removes the default.conf file and then copies the `nginx.conf` file from my host to the image:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And my `nginx.conf` file that gets copied into the image looks like this:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /api/customers {
            proxy_pass         http://service-a:3500;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /api/products {
            proxy_pass         http://service-b:3501;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

When I `docker-compose up` everything spins up fine, but when I POST to one of my endpoints (for example, localhost:80/api/customers) then nginx responds with a 502. But if I `docker container stop reverseproxy` and then `docker container start reverseproxy`, then everything works as expected and I'm able to hit my endpoints with localhost:80.

I was able to `docker exec -it reverseproxy /bin/sh` and was able to verify that `default.conf` is gone and `nginx.conf` was copied over from my host as expected. I have followed the sample configuration from the nginx page on Docker Hub and most tutorials online show a nearly identical set up.

What may be causing this? How could make my nginx revereproxy service work as expected without restarting the container?

Edit: I am using Postman to make my requests localhost:80

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but, why did you get into a complicated extend that would see you remove a config file and add a new one when you could have just override default.conf with your own file? `COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/default.conf`

Comment: Does it help if you say the nginx container `depends_on: [service-a, service-b]`?  Is there any more information in the nginx logs than just the 502 error?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Not a stupid question at all... I followed the suggested Dockerfile from nginx: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/#manage_copy

Comment: Mhm, interesting... from what I see in the image doc, they rather say to use `/etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template` in order to do so.

Comment: Or they even fully override /etc/nginx/nginx.conf https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

Comment: @DavidMaze you were correct! Totally makes sense and attributed the answer to you below.

Answer (score 1):

@DavidMaze had the correct solution -- thank you!

```
  reverseproxy:
    container_name: reverseproxy
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - "service-a"
      - "service-b"
```

Makes sense that it only works as expected on a restarted because the other services were available by then. Just tried it out and it works as expected.